# Graphic artififacts on rotated view using hardwarelayer and semi transparent border as background

Tags: android, view, transparency

I'm trying to remove the graphic artifacts from an android application visible on the attached screenshot.

The View is rotated and has a 9-patch border with partial transparency set as it's background.
One of the child view's has a white background which together somehow end up creating this weird effect around the transparent border.

This only seems to happen when the softkeyboard is activated and the main view is shrinked.

The following drawfilter is set in the parentlayout:

```
@Override
protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.setDrawFilter(new PaintFlagsDrawFilter(0, Paint.DEV_KERN_TEXT_FLAG | Paint.SUBPIXEL_TEXT_FLAG | Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG | Paint.FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG | Paint.DITHER_FLAG));
    super.dispatchDraw(canvas);
}
```

If no hardwarelayer is being used the artifacts disappear. Same goes for using a border without transparency.

Anyone has a clue what creates this effect and how it can be removed?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I noticed a similar artifact with an animated view in one of my apps. That artifact only appears on my Jelly Bean tablet. The view is being scaled and rotated during the animation and that leaves some traces of the edges behind just like in your screenshot. There was one older Jelly Bean version where these artifacts used to be permanent. Since the latest updates they are only visible during the animation and disappear when the animation ends. Since it's always the edges you could try adding some padding to your white paper background. Maybe the artifacts disappear then.

Comment: the screenshot is from a S3 with Android 4.1.2 using nineoldandroids for rotation and animation. I already tried adding a padding and even a margin to the child elements but that did not seem to help.

Comment: I feel your pain. Sometimes these things happen and it leaves a bad mark on us developers (who else to blame). Have you tried using "vanilla" Animations instead of nineoldandroids? You could also try playing around with switching on / off hardware acceleration for the view or whole activity. I suspect there is a connection since it's a relatively new feature of Android.